# Are Unity3D questions on-topic for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions

Is it OK to ask a question about Unity 3D on Stack Overflow? I seem to be unable to get help on the Unity 3D forums, and would like to know if I can ask my questions here instead.

Comment: if it is programming related, sure

Comment: here it is http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/player-does-not-collide-with-walls-unity-5.318832/

Comment: Please consider whether [GameDev.SE] would be a better fit for your question. And please do not simply post a link to your question. You have to state a full and self-containing question _either_ on Stack Overflow _or_ Game Development. Please also take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn on how to improve your question. Moreover, please be aware that the tag [[tag:unity]] has different meanings on Stack Overflow and Game Development. You are using the wrong tag in this question.

Comment: First they came for Unity, and I did not speak out, because I didn't use Unity...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi That's quite a lot too dramatic. Especially as there's simply no way we will ban it, even if it should rival php in amount of crap posted...

Comment: @Deduplicator, what a coincidence, PHP was my choice for the second verse. Seriously, it was half a joke, *dramatic* was part of it.

Answer (score 23):

Unity3D is a software development platform. Stack Overflow is a site for asking questions about software development. While GDSE is an appropriate place for Unity questions, SO is as well.

We don't forbid [opengl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/opengl) questions because most of them are from/about game development. We don't forbid [corona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/corona) or [love2d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/love2d) or any number of other programming tools that are primarily intended for game development.

Why should [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d) be so special?

I get that you don't want to see them, because a larger proportion of them are terrible questions. I'm sick of seeing Minecraft-clone "How do I render a bunch of cubes" OpenGL questions too. But that's no excuse for banning them outright.

Either SO is a programming site or it isn't. We shouldn't make exceptions just because some languages/tools/etc tend to be used by people who ask bad questions.

Comment: Is this to say that questions about how to use the tool, in a way not directly involving scripting are on topic? For example, how to use the editor to add a new Game Object?

Answer (score 8):

Unity3D, which is tagged [unity3d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d), is absolutely on-topic on Stack Overflow if what you're asking is a programming question. That is, code needs to be involved and you have to clearly demonstrate where you are at and what the problem you're facing is.

No matter the site, this may sometimes be somewhat difficult due to the nature of Unity. Its visual programming aspect may mean that some of the trickier parts to your question could be due to how your hierarchy has been set up and what your component settings are. In this case you'll have to isolate the problem yourself until you can show us more with a relevant screenshot or such.

The bottom line is that if you actually show us what your programming problem is and how we can reproduce it, you'll be fine. If we have to guess at it because we don't have the complete picture, it won't be.